# Which GPU instance to opt for in Google Cloud?

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, google-cloud

I am looking to rent a GPU instance in Google Cloud **for casual deep learning model training purposes** and wondered about the differences between the available Nvidia Tesla versions which are

- Nvidia Tesla T4
- Nvidia Tesla P4
- Nvidia Tesla V100
- Nvidia Tesla P100
- Nvidia Tesla K80

Here is the [GPU Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/gpus-pricing) page.

If anyone has used it or currently doing or know the best GPU to rent it'll be appreciated if you can share your experience or knowledge about it.

Comment: For casual purpose, you should try Colab and Kaggle Kernel's first

Comment: I'm already using those for quite sometime. Want to migrate due to storage issues.

Comment: It actually depends on how much you are ready to pay for them on average. A sweet choice is TeslaT4..

Comment: I see...thanks for the suggestion!